# What is the difference in meaning between "European history" and "the history of Europe"?

Tags: adjectives, adjectival-phrases

I came across this in *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*. An explanation was also provided in the book, but I am looking for a more complete explanation.

Comment: I don't see a difference, so I would be interested to know what their explanation was!

Comment: You could argue that "European history" is history about or written by Europeans, while "the history of Europe" is the history of the continent of Europe. However, I think most people would agree with @KateBunting and say they were actually the same thing.

Comment: @KillingTime: So, by that definition, European exploration and colonization of the New World would be included in "European history" but not in "the history of Europe"?

Comment: @Dan Not so much a definition as an interpretation but, yes, European exploration/colonization anywhere in the world could be seen as "European history".

Answer (score 3):

You could quote the book.  The actual point being made there is about the use of *the* in "the history of Europe" in contrast to no *the* in "European history". It says there might be a slight difference in that

- *She's studying the history of Europe* might imply she is studying it as a whole, while
- *She's studying European history* allows the interpretation she is only studying some aspects of it or taking a particular college course.

I would agree that this difference is small and in many cases the two phrases are likely to be intended to mean the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for this information, which the OP did not provide.

Comment: This is the best explanation. Although as you say often they have no differences. If someone is described as an expert on European history, I'd expect them to know the whole history in outline even if they're an expert on a period, rather than just know 1815-1870 and never have heard of Stalin or Louis XIV. But history can't neatly be divided by period or location, because everything interacts.

Answer (score 1):

### European history does not have to happen in Europe

The European history of Australia means the history of Australia as impacted by Europeans, that is, since colonisation or of the pre-colonisation European explorers and traders.

This is different from the Australian history of Europe which would cover the activities of Australians in Europe or the impact on Europe of Australia.